# Set headers in JSON get request

Tags: json, go

I'm getting JSON resonse from an external API with the following way:

```
func Request(url string, contentType string) []byte {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    resp.Header.Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return body
}

url := fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/api/category/%s", category)
contentType := "application/json"
body := Request(url, contentType)

res := &JSONRespStruct{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), res)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The problem if I start to benchmark my site with `go-wrk`, the server crashes with the following error message:

```
2018/01/02 12:13:35 invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

I think the code try to parse the JSON response as HTML. How I can force to get the response as a JSON?

Comment: Add `log.Println(string(body))` after you read the bytes with `ioutil.ReadAll` to see if it's valid json.

Comment: Setting the header on a response after you've retrieved it with `http.Get` has zero effect on how the response's Body is read. You can omit that line.

Comment: You probably need to set the header on the http request rather than response. `req.Header.Set("name", "value")` is how you do it.

Comment: **Server** crashed? Please show suspected crashing code instead of the **client**.

Comment: The error states, quite clearly that the response contains an unexpected `<`, which leads me to believe you're getting an HTML/XML response back (not JSON). Create a request, set the `Accept` header to `application/json` and make sure you're calling the API correctly

Comment: I just logged the response to the console and the last request, where the server crashes, indeed returning a html error page with 403 (Down for maintenance). Probably the API that I using is rate limited?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to set the header on the request. Setting the header on the response has no impact.

```
func Request(url string, contentType string) []byte {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return body
}
```

Comment: I just logged the response to the console and the last request, where the server crashes, indeed returning a html error page with 403 (Down for maintenance). Probably the API that I using is rate limited?

Comment: I accepting your answer, because it's solving the proper header setting.